# isomorphism between function space and complex matrices

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

How would you show that $\mathcal{L}(X) \cong \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, where $X= \mathbb{C}^{n}$. Note that $\mathcal{L}(X)$ denotes the space of linear bounded functions on $X$. Is this a  specific case of a more general result?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Since we are dealing with finite dimensions, every linear function from $X \to X$ is bounded, so we are merely looking at the space of linear functions.  Your question now states that the space of linear functions from an $n$-dimensional vector space to itself is isomorphic to the space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: Pick a basis, and consider the matrix associated to a linear operator with respect to that basis.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Yes I understand. You can show that there exists a linear bijection between $\mathcal{L}$ and $C^{n \times n}$. Can we further show that they are isomorphic as normed spaces? Maybe linear surjective isometries?

Comment: Well, any two norms are equivalent on these spaces, so you can choose a norm that makes it an isometry.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan What is the general result which allows your statement that "any two norms on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ and $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ are equivalent"? I understand that any norms on each space respectively are equivalent (since it is finite dimensional) but why does this imply that the norms on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ and $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ are equivalent?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26595/discussion-on-question-by-moses-isomorphism-between-function-space-and-complex-m).